# Web application on a mobile platform

Tags: mobile, sencha-touch-2

First, my question might sound like a duplicate, but I have been going through a lot of questions on this forum and haven't found the answer to what I am looking for.

I have an existing web application built using Java, struts2 and jsps. I want the web site to be mobile - friendly. I am not looking at developing native apps right now. I want the mobile-site to have a native-app like appearance. So if a user goes to the browser on a mobile and accesses my site it should have that native look and feel. So I looked at Sencha touch 2 to begin with. I am new to Mobile development and would appreciate help in understanding how to go about evaluating Sencha touch 2 as a viable option. I see from examples that in ST the UI is mostly built using ExtJs javascript.

My questions are the following

> 1. Is there a way to port my existing jsps and html to the mobile view , without building them from scratch?
> 2. Since the css for the site is currently built for 'screen' media, this will obviously have to be worked out , but does Sencha Touch
>      provide any functionality of using an existing css and customising it
>      for a mobile device?

Appreciate your help,

Comment: Would appreciate if anyone can point me to some other framework that would be a better fit for my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer to your first question is no.

Java/JSP and Javascript are totally different in essence. No convention could be made to convert between these two.

For the second one, SASS/SCSS might be the things you're looking for: http://sass-lang.com/. It's because Sencha Touch components' CSS properties are build through SCSS files. You can take advantage of these. For further ideas, see: http://www.sencha.com/blog/an-introduction-to-theming-sencha-touch